# How to speed up this triple loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a triple nested for loop in matlab and it takes enormous amount of time to solve it. Do you have any recommendations how can I speed up the simulation? This specific simulation is fast, but in the real code the 't' has thousand elements and and A and B about 400 elements.

```
A = [1,2,3];
B = [1,2];
t=[1:1:4];
or hh = 1:length(t)
    for ii = 1:length(A)
        T1(ii,hh)=A(ii)*t(hh)
            for jj = 1:length(B)
                T2(ii,jj,hh)=A(ii)*B(jj)*t(hh)
            end
    end
end

T1_part=sum(T1);
T2_part1=sum(sum(T2));
T2_part2=T2_part1(:,:);
T_final=T1_part+T2_part2
```

Results :
T_final =

```
24    48    72    96
```

Comment: Just to be clear: I assume the real `A`, `b` and `t` are not `[1 2 3 ..]`?

Comment: How slow is this? Is this taking about 0.5 seconds? Have you tried parfor instead of for?

Comment: The posted code takes 0.005s, but in my real code, when I left it running took over 7 hours and then I stopped it. 

No the real numbers for A, B and t are with smaller increments and different.

Comment: 5 milliseconds to 7 hours means five million times slower. You need more cores(maybe more cache too)(probably a cuda enabled gpu) and a function like Dan's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing the loops with:

```
T1 = A'*t;
T2 = bsxfun(@times, A'*B, permute(t,[3 1 2]));
```

The reason for the permute is because `bsxfun` will expand the matrix along a singleton dimension so you need to make sure that your matrix expands along the right dimension. If you give `bsxfun` a row vector and a matrix, it will try do an element-wise multiplication of your row vector and each row of your matrix. But what we want is to multiply the entire matrix with each element of a vector but along a new orthogonal dimension. So permute changes the vector from a row vector to a 3D vector allowing `bsxfun` to expand along the correct dimension.

But then also you should first try to just [pre-allocate memory](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html) for `T1` and `T2` using `zeros`, i.e. before your loop just try `T2 = zeros(size(A,2), size(B,2), size(t,2))`. You should always preallocate when possible when using a loop.

Comment: Can this bsxfun use gpu arrays to make it faster?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I believe that it should be, `bsxfun` has apparently been multithreaded since R2009a

Comment: Does preallocation make better memory management for those tight multiplications?

Comment: Thanks a lot, that speeds things up a lot.
But what if I have to multiply A*B*C*t , where C = [1,2,3,4,5] for example. And I dont understand the permute purpose? Can you elaborate what does it do?

Comment: @user3200392 I've added an explanation. If you have a 4th vector, you might have to add another step. It really depends on what output you require.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I don't know what you're asking. Preallocation makes loops run much much faster. It doesn't use less memory but in a sense it is better memory management as you don't have to reassign memory each iteration. It won't do anything for my vectorized solution though, just for the loops solution. However it can make loops so much faster that there become no need for vectorization.

Comment: @Dan you mean preallocation is a kind of unmanaged memory that is in C space and can be accessed in a SIMD style instructions that needs continuous memory access? Versus mallocing new memory every time in iterations.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik something like that, there are plenty of articles explaining why you should preallocate in Matlab that can give you better explanations.

Comment: I tried the pre-allocating zeros to T1 and T2. And funnily the time increased to finish the simulation. How can this be explained?

Comment: @user3200392 http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html

Answer (score 0):

for both T1 and T2 you can use the element-wise product of two vectors, which gives you a matrix :

```
A = [1,2,3];
B = [1,2];

> T1=B'*A

T1 =

     1     2     3
     2     4     6
```